# How do I make Webpack 2 write chunks to a location shared by multiple apps?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

Webpack allows you [split code into chunks](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) so that different **parts of one app** can selectively request shared code. But at first glance Webpack does not seem to split code into chunks **shared between multiple apps** to a prescribed location.

Assume that I have two packages A and B with the **same dependencies**, where I split my code into code for the app, shared code internal to my business, and vendor code. If I use the same Webpack config to build these two apps (with content hashes to make this interesting), I'm going to get this:

```
A/
    A-b612[...].js
    shared-a8fe[...].js
    vendor-9eaa[...].js
    index-24ac[...].html
B/
    B-77fe[...].js
    shared-a8fe[...].js
    vendor-9eaa[...].js
    index-cab4[...].html
```

When I want this:

```
shared/
    shared-a8fe[...].js
    vendor-9eaa[...].js    
A/
    A-b612[...].js
    index-24ac[...].html # <script> for chunks point to public URL for /shared 
B/
    B-77fe[...].js
    index-cab4[...].html # Ditto
```

It seems that Webpack just doesn't handle this use case because all talk of code splitting, multiple entry points and chunks **apply to apps independently**, not as part of a platform.

If I build common code as an entirely separate package or use [`resolve.alias`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias), that still does not solve the problem because each app still gets a copy of the chunk.

**Is there a way to configure Webpack 2 to build multiple apps such that common code exist independently of the apps, and that code is not copied for each app?**

Answer (score 0):

The solution appears to be [Externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) in light of Webpack's notes on [authoring libraries](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/). From the Webpack docs, emphasis mine:

> The `externals` configuration option provides a way of excluding dependencies from the output bundles. Instead, the created bundle relies on that dependency to be present in the consumer's environment.

This allows you to author a library, build it in Webpack seperately from your app, and then tell the apps that you bundle with Webpack to treat those other bundles as dependencies in a slightly different way depending on their module type and if they have a global variable holding the interface.

Cache busting is less clear in this case, because authoring a Webpack library requires [setting the `main` key in package.json](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/), and doing that manually for each new hash would be a pain.